# Search from every pages in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

i want to add search in my website and i want search from my pages (html)

** note : i want grab the label tag , i mean for example :

i have label tag called ' test ' and when user write in search bar 'test' i want view the label to user in new page

- my label like this :

```html
<label id="label_main_app">
    <img id="img_main_app_first_screen" src="{% static " images/android_studio.jpg " %}" alt=""> test
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="p_size_first_page">this is an test app
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.fb.com" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><big> See More & Download </big></a>
    </p>
</label>
```

- always i got this message in result page : not found

my code : * this form in home html page

```html
<form class="" action="{% url 'test_search_page'%}" method="get">
    <div class="md-form mt-0 search-bar" id="search_form">
        <input id="search_box" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="searchFunction()" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Write Here to Search ..." aria-label="Search" name="search">
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my view.py code :

```py
def search(request):
    input= 'search'
    my_template_keyword = ['label']
    if 'search' in request.GET and request.GET['search'] and input == my_template_keyword:
        return render(request, 'home_page/testforsearch.html', {'search:':search})`
```

finally this is my code in html result page :

```html
<div class="container">
    {% if search %}
        {{ search }}
    {% else %}
        <h2>not found</h2>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

any help please ?

Comment: On thing I don't understand is in `views.py` you first assign `input='search'` and then `my_template_keyword = ['label']`. In your `if` statement, test if `input == my_template_keyword` which are definitely not equal right?

Comment: yes it's not equal ,, what i must do ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the query for database search. Use generic display views like this:

```html
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Videos


class Search(ListView):
    model = Videos
    template_name = "/search.html"
    paginate_by = 30

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if query:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.none()
        return object_list
```

Comment: i already tried this but doesn't work for me
any other help please ?